# Data Inserting in MongoDB without Request Data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, body-parser

Kindly request you to point out where I am going wrong.
When I make a POST Request to the URL: http://localhost:1030/apirequestlogs/add
Record is Created in the Collection. However, Only _id, createDate & updateDate Parameters are there in the record.

app.js

```
let express = require('express');
let path = require('path'); // Required for Routing
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let cors = require('cors'); // Required for Sending & Receiving Data in Chunk
let bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // Required for Handling URL GET & POST Requests
let dbConfig = require('./db/dbConfig');
let createError = require('http-errors');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(dbConfig.db, {
    useNewUrlParser: true
}).then(() => {
    console.log('Database BE Server Listening on Port 27017');
},
(error) => {
    console.log('Error Connecting to msermsdbs Database BE Server. ' + error);
});

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors());

const apirequestlogRoute = require('./models/common/logs/apirequests/apirequestlogRoutes');
app.use('/apirequestlogs', apirequestlogRoute);

const port = process.env.port || 1030;
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Database FE Server Listening on Port 1030');
});

app.use((request, response, next) => {
    next(createError(404));
});

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    request.send('Invalid Request'); 
});

app.use(function(error, request, response, next){
    if(!error.statusCode) error.statusCode = 500;
    response.status(error.statusCode).send(error.message);
});
```

apirequestlogModel.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
let apirequestlogSchema = new Schema({
    nid: Number,
    host: String,
    url: String,
    server: String,
    haserror: Boolean,
    errorcode: Number,
    errordescription: String
}, 
{
    timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("logapirequests", apirequestlogSchema);
```

apirequestlogRoutes.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const apirequestlogRoute = express.Router();
let apirequestlogModel = require('./apirequestlogModel');

apirequestlogRoute.route('/getall').get((request, response) => {
    apirequestlogModel.find((error, data) => {
        if(error){
            return next(error);
        } else {            
            response.json(data);
        };
    });
});

apirequestlogRoute.route('/getbyid/:id').get((request, response) => {
    apirequestlogModel.findById(request.params.id,(error, data) => {
        if(error){
            return next(error);
        } else {            
            response.json(data);
        };
    });
});

apirequestlogRoute.route('/add').post((request, response, next) => {
    apirequestlogModel.create(request.body,(error, data) => {        
        if(error){
            return next(error);
        } else {            
            response.json(data);
        };
    });
});

module.exports = apirequestlogRoute;
```

Postman POST Request

```
{   
    "nid": 123,
    "host": "localhost",
    "url": "http://localhost:1030",
    "server": "localhost",
    "haserror": true,
    "errorcode": 500,
    "errordescription": "Not Found"
}
```

Postman Output

```
{
    "_id": "6299e1de7106c03a3c6cc06c",
    "createdAt": "2022-06-03T10:26:38.494Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-06-03T10:26:38.494Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

[Postman Request & Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YzOA.png)

Record Created in Database

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6299cd8ee20fd12125ec4c16"), "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-06-03T08:59:58.558Z"), "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-06-03T08:59:58.558Z"), "__v" : 0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct. In postman I was making post request as text instead of json.